# Billing date in PayPal recurrent payments

Tags: paypal

I am using paypal rest API for recurrent billing.

Is there any way to predict date for next payment for billing agreement?

When I create & execute agreement, paypal will provide me this info:

```
"start_date": "2014-10-26T07:00:00Z",
"cycles_remaining": "1",
"cycles_completed": "0",
"next_billing_date": "2014-10-26T10:00:00Z",
"final_payment_date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"failed_payment_count": "0"
```

When I check transactions after next_billing_date, there is no payment. However, after a longer time a payment arrive and when I retrieve the same agreement, I get this:

```
"start_date": "2014-10-26T07:00:00Z",
"agreement_details": {
    "outstanding_balance": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "0.00"
    },
    "cycles_remaining": "0",
    "cycles_completed": "0",
    "next_billing_date": "2014-11-26T10:00:00Z",
    "last_payment_date": "2014-10-28T05:00:55Z",
    "last_payment_amount": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "0.01"
    },
    "final_payment_date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "failed_payment_count": "0"
```

So the payment was made 1d 19h after the date provided in agreement.

If those 'delays' will be max 3 days, it will be OK. But I need to be sure.

EDIT: I should specify, that this happens in sandbox environment

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After switching to "Live"/production environment everything is running well.

First transaction occured in first 30 minutes, and following ones in about an hour after next_billing_date.

In sandbox only first payment was made to this date(ref to data in Q). "Funny" thing is, that not only sandbox, but even their support seems to be broken...

Also see [Tell PayPal to automatically process the monthly payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562515/tell-paypal-to-automatically-process-the-monthly-payment?rq=1)