# PayPal billing agreements time zone and returned time

Tags: php, datetime, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using [php paypal sdk](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/) to implement recurrent payaments. I am basing the renewal of subscriptions on the `AgreementDetails.next_billing_date` field.

In the agreement details, I am getting the `next_billing_date = 2016-11-07T10:00:00Z`. From [Zulu Time zone](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z), the `Z` at in the end of the date means that the time zone of the date is `UTC`. However, the sandbox website and the `last_payment_date` field both show that the payment was executed at `2016-11-07 13:11:25` `UTC`

Note that I am always getting the next billing date at `10:00:00` independent of the `start_date` of the agreemnt.

Also note that the `last_payment_date` is returning the correct date and time in `UTC`. So, I assume that this is not a time zone issue.

So, I am confused. Is it the case that PayPal needs `3-4` hours to execute payments? 
Or is it a bug that the `next_billing_date` will always be at `10:00:00` no matter when the payment is going to be executed? and if it is the latter, Is there another way to know when the next payment is due?

Comment: Could be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607683/billing-date-in-paypal-recurrent-payments